# Adding Column at partition level in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Am new to hive, We had requirement to add columns to existing hive table.
I did that with the help of below command.
alter table tableName add columns (colName datatype) cascade;

But in hive documentation, we have alter command to add columns at partition level.
I tried below commands.

```
hive> SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
hive> alter table test_alter_col partition(c=1) add columns (d1 int);
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Duplicate column name: d1
hive> select d1 from test_alter_col where c=1;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:7 Invalid table alias or column reference 'd1': (possible column names are: a1, b1, d, c)
hive> alter table test_alter_col partition(c=1) add columns (d2 int);
OK
Time taken: 0.178 seconds
hive> select d2 from test_alter_col where c=1;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:7 Invalid table alias or column reference 'd2': (possible column names are: a1, b1, d, c)
hive>
```

What exactly does the above command do and is there any use case for using alter command at partition level.

Edit 1 -

Have tried below commands as well, but still neither i am able to query newly added column nor able to insert the data.

```
create table test_partn (a int, b int, c int) partitioned by (d int) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile;

insert into table test_partn partition(d) values (1, 11, 111, 1111), (2, 22, 222, 2222), (3, 33, 333, 3333);

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;

alter table test_partn partition(d=1111) add columns (e int);
insert into test_partn partition(d=1111) values (1, 12, 13, 14);
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:12 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different '1111': Table insclause-0 has 3 columns, but query has 4 columns.

alter table test_partn partition(d=3333) add columns (e int) restrict;
insert into test_partn partition(d=3333) values (1, 12, 13, 14);
```

Thank You,
Vijay

Answer (score 1):

> hive> alter table test_alter_col partition(c=1) add columns (d1 int);
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Duplicate column name: d1
>   h

Regarding your first command, it seems that there is already a duplicate column name in your hive table. You need to use a different column.

Alternatively, if you want to add a column to an already partitioned hive table, you can use the below command:

`ALTER TABLE <table name> ADD columns (column1 string) CASCADE;`

The above should do your work of adding a column to an already partitioned table. Catch here is the CASCADE keyword which will cascade the changes to all of the partitions in hive.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, i am able to add columns to all the partitions using cascade, but when i add add column for single partition, then neither i am able to query that column (d2) or add the same column again (d1 which was added earlier). Wanted to know what exactly happens when we add column to single partition instead of all. Hope you get my question

Answer (score 0):

I think it adding columns at partition level will only add the col names at metadata level.

i tried with query - `describe extended tablename partition (keycol=value)`

Below are the results.

```
hive> describe extended test_partn partition(d=1111);
OK
a                       int
b                       int
c                       int
e                       int
d                       int

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

d                       int

Detailed Partition Information  Partition(values:[1111], dbName:test, tableName:test_partn, createTime:1539261860, lastAccessTime:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:a, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:b, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:c, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:e, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:d, type:int, comment:null)], location:maprfs:/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/test_partn/d=1111, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=     , field.delim=
Time taken: 0.139 seconds, Fetched: 12 row(s)
hive>
```

I can see the newly added columns only for this partition